# Manager postponed my internal transition date

Tags: transition

I work at a large company and it is a great company to work, great perks and benefits. However, I have a terrible manager for a few months ago, he is arrogant, knows everything attitude, makes fun of my introvert behavior and etc. I like my team and the company but I despise the manager.

Long story short I applied internally and I got a job at a very different part of the company. I had three other external interviews and HR convinced me to cancel my upcoming interviews.

Today I have been told my transition date will be in a month instead of two weeks. I really don't think I can stay in my team for one more month. The manager is unbearable.

I am not sure what are my options at this point.

Comment: Stick it out another month, or keep interviewing externally.

Comment: What reasoning did they give for prolonging the transition? Can they prolong it a second/third/etc. time?

Comment: How did HR know that you had three other external interviews and why did you cancel them?

Comment: @sf02 I am an honest person, I told them.

Comment: There's a difference between honesty and divulging unnecessary information.  You should never advertise to your current company that you are seeking work at other companies, it usually never works out in your favor.

Comment: @sf02 agreed. I learned my lesson

Comment: Bear in mind this may be just because the new team aren't quite ready yet. Someone on holiday, an impending busy period, could mean it's just not convenient to take someone new on for another couple of weeks.

Answer (score 8):

At this point it's unlikely there's going to be anything you can do that will be faster than just waiting the additional two weeks.

You could go back on the hunt for an external job - but unless you find something *really* quickly and have a *really* short notice period it's doubtful you're going to save you much time - and you know that the current issue is going to get resolved.

You might be best off looking for ways to reduce your exposure to your current manager over the next month - do you have any vacation time available? Work remotely etc